# Show/Hide a Div based on click on another Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show/hide a `div` with id `Info_Holder` based on click on another `div` with id `Get_Indo`. Below is my code -

**HTML**

```js
function showHide() {
  var e = document.getElementById('Info_Holder');

  if (e.style.display == 'none') {
    e.style.display = 'block';
    e.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    e.style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#Info_Holder {
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 50%;
          display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: center; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
          font-size: 22px; color: #232323; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); z-index: 1000;
          position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 60%; transform: translateY(-50%);" id="Get_Indo" onclick="showHide()">
  &#9432;</div>

<div style="height: 180px; width: 400px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
            right: -10px; top: 54px; padding: 5px; cursor: auto;" id="Info_Holder">
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 7px; overflow: hidden; 
              border: 1px solid #ECECEC; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #dbdbdb;">
    <div id="A"> Source</div>
    <div id="B" , style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 10px; font-size: 10px; color: #666666; text-align: left;">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page should start from `hide` mode. However when `click` on `Get_Indo` first time, nothing happen. `JS` appears to get triggered only after 2nd `click`.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/OJyZZXd

Any pointer what exactly is broken will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `.style` doesn't get styles that are inherited from CSS, only inline styles and styles that were added by JS.

Comment: You need to use `getComputedStyle()` to include inherited styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
if (e.style.display == 'none') {
```

but your element does NOT have style="display: none". You have this in CSS but it is not the same. `e.style` will include only what you have inline with style="" and not CSS.

Just add `display: none` to style.

```
<div style="display: none; height: 180px; width: 400px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
        right: -10px; top: 54px; padding: 5px; cursor: auto;" id="Info_Holder">
```

```js
function showHide() {
  var e = document.getElementById('Info_Holder');

  if (e.style.display == 'none') {
    e.style.display = 'block';
    e.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    e.style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#Info_Holder {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 50%;
          display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: center; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
          font-size: 22px; color: #232323; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); z-index: 1000;
          position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 60%; transform: translateY(-50%);" id="Get_Indo" onclick="showHide()">
  &#9432;</div>

<div style="height: 180px; width: 400px; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
            right: -10px; top: 54px; padding: 5px; cursor: auto; display: none" id="Info_Holder">
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 7px; overflow: hidden; 
              border: 1px solid #ECECEC; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #dbdbdb;">
    <div id="A"> Source</div>
    <div id="B" , style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 10px; font-size: 10px; color: #666666; text-align: left;">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailing the problem why it was not working

Comment: puttting style code in html is the worst way. It is againsy to clean code.I suggest you to not put css code to your html tags. @Bogaso

Answer (score 4):

Just initialize your element as none [Demo](https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/ZEbooRe)

```
document.getElementById('Info_Holder').style.display= 'none' ;
```

or just change your if condition like to take from your css code [Demo](https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/mdeLKrd)

```
getComputedStyle(e).display=='none'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
||e.style.display==''
```

In your if statement, that should work.